# . Net Core Web Api Authentication with Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

Hı ,

I have .Net Core 2.0 Web Api project which is make Crud operation in Mongo Db. I want to put secure in my api. Like basic authentication,JWT token like MsSql or dont necessarry database but I didn't understand tutorials. They seen me very complex. How can ı add authentication in my Web api with Mongo Db? thats my main question.

I new on MongoDb

Answer (score 0):

You can use AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo 
Get from Nuget
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).